# How to get timestamp in UTC or system time for a frame in gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm using `uridecodebin` to capture live streams, and I feed frames into `appsink`. I need to  record timestamp for a received frame either in UTC or system time. So far I managed to receive PTS timestamp:

```
guint64 timestamp = GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP(buffer)
```

from which I can get running time and stream time:

```
guint64 pos = gst_segment_to_stream_time(segment, GST_FORMAT_TIME, timestamp);
guint64 run_time = gst_segment_to_running_time(segment, GST_FORMAT_TIME, timestamp)
```

For first frame `pos` is always `0`, but `run_time` is around `7008 ms`. Why is that? I dont  understand where that time is coming from.

And for main part of the question, how do I get timestamp that can relate appsink frame as close as possible to the actual time frame was captured in system time or UTC?